# How can I initialize NetOffice.WordApi objects using a Microsoft.Office.Interop objects?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, office-interop, netoffice

I have a Microsoft Office Addin Project on Visual Studio. It uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.dll . 
Within the code logic, I need to use NetOffice.WordApi instead of the regular Interop assemblies. 
My question is this: Since NetOffice is a wrapper to Microsoft.Office.Interop.dll , How can I initialize a NetOffice.WordApi objects using a Microsoft.Office.Interop objects (e.g. Application -> Application , INDocument -> NODocument or Table to Table)

Answer (score 2):

Every class in NetOffice have a constructor that allows you to wrap an existing `__ComObject`:

```
public Application(COMObject parentObject, object comProxy) : base(parentObject, comProxy)
{
    // ...
}
```

The first parameter expects a parent NetOffice COMObject (which you don't have), so pass `null` and the second is your `__ComObject`.

Thus:

```
var wrappedApp = new Application(null, yourInteropObject);
```